# Apt repository is not listed in /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: drivers, apt, updates, debian

i have installed amd gpu drivers and ended that

but now , when  want to run an `apt update` command , i get problem with amd repository in my apt commmand

here accessing directing to amd things is blocked by ISP , and its a big problem to me , i am getting errore's when i want to update my apt command
i have tried to rmove that from /etc/apt/sources.list
but there is no amd repository to remove

can you say where is the repository to remove?

```
  GNU nano 5.4                                          /etc/apt/sources.list                                                   
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 11.2.0 _Bullseye_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20211218-11:12]/ bullseye main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 11.2.0 _Bullseye_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20211218-11:12]/ bullseye main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main

# bullseye-updates, to get updates before a point release is made;
# see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_updates_and_backports
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main
```

and also i get this when i want run `apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                     
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                                                          
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                                                                  
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu jammy Release                                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 8*******9 34897]
Hit:6 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                       
Hit:7 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/21.40.1/ubuntu focal InRelease             
Hit:8 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian ubuntu InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Thanks for reading and maybe helping

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like what's causing the problem is the `ubuntuhandbook1` PPA. APT reads the source repositories both from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and from all files contained in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

My first guess would be to try and check whether the PPA is defined on a file under that directory. You can check the contents of that directory with `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`. If you do find the PPA there you can either delete the file altogether or just move it somewhere else (i.e. `mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/foo.list ~` to move it to your home directory). After that, try to update the repositories once more with `apt update` and see what you get.

If this solution doesn't work feel free to comment on the answer. Best of luck!

Comment: thanks , worked ,i have not enough score to upvote you , then i just can confirm this answer and say thanks

Comment: No worries! Glad to have helped!